# Did the Romans ever encounter the Vikings?

Tags: roman-empire, vikings

Did the Romans ever scout Scandinavia for possible conquest? Or was trade ever done between them?

Comment: Certainly the Roman Empire had a long relationship with those Scandinavian peoples termed the *Goths*, of both the *Visi-* and *Ostro-* variety, from roughly the second to seventh centuries AD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goths.

Comment: Who are the "Romans"? Residents of the city of Rome? Residents of the Western Roman empire (which on paper existed until 476)? Or some other people? The answer strongly depends on this.

Comment: Just to clarify I'm asking about the Ancient Romans in the west,but I think the question has been answered brillantly

Comment: @turinsbane: But there were no Vikings at the time of Ancient Rome!

Comment: @turinsbane: The earliest mentioning of "Vikings" was in in the end of 8th century. Or you consider ALL residents of Scandinavia at all times as "Vikings"?

Comment: "Vikingr" means "raider". A Scandinavian chieftain would "go viking" for a season.

Comment: If you include the Byzantines as being "Roman" descendants, then look up the Varagian Guard:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varangian_Guard

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Constantinople_(860)

Comment: @turinsbane Since you've quite recently edited the question, it appears both that you are still interested in an answer, and do not accept any of the current answers as satisfying. I would put a bounty on this question, except that first I would ask that you further clarify the points that were raised. Please provide a time period and two definitions: What, to you, is a _viking_? and What, to you, do you consider _Romans_ to be?

Comment: The Goths-(and their diverse tribesmen), would have been of distant Scandinavian ethnic origin. However, when we hear about the Goths during Roman times, they have become, a distinctly unique Germanic peoples.

Answer (score 45):

The question is illogical because there was no such thing as a viking in the days of the undivided Roman Empire or of the Western Roman Empire.

A viking is defined as a Scandinavian pirate or sea raider during the period of about 795 to 1100 AD at the widest.  It is always incorrect to capitalize viking and use it as an ethnic word instead of an occupational word. Thus it is impossible for western Romans before 476 AD to ever encounter vikings since no Scandinavians ever went on viking raids to Roman territories until after the western Roman Empire fell.

But Roman citizens and subjects and Scandinavians did meet sometimes.

1. For example, Roman artifacts have been unearthed from Scandinavian Roman era sites.  Each artifact was either transported to Scandinavia in stages, passing from one trader to another, or else was transported to Scandinavia in one long trip.  In the latter case, either Scandinavians acquired Roman artifacts in Roman territory, thus meeting Roman citizens and subjects, or else Roman traders and/or diplomats transported them to Scandinavia, thus meeting Scandinavians.
2. And there were Saxon sea raiders who raided the "Saxon Shore" of Roman Britain and Gaul during the late empire.  In those days the Romans used the word "Saxon" to refer to not only Saxons, but other northern Germanic peoples who raided Roman lands by sea.  Thus it is possible that some of those "Saxons" were Angles, Jutes, and other Scandinavians.  If there were any Scandinavians among those "Saxons" making proto-viking type raids on Roman lands, they might have used the word "viking" to describe their occupation.
   Of course modern historians would not approve of using the word "viking" to describe such raiders centuries before the age of vikings.
3. And as written in andejons' answer, the Roman battles with the Cimbrians may have been with migrants from Scandinavia.
4. There were a lot of Germanic mercenaries in the Roman army, and **SOME** of them **MIGHT** have been Scandinavians.
5. Radagaisus, a Gothic King, led a horde of barbarians in an invasion of Italy in 405-406 before being defeated by Flavius Stilicho.  The invaders included Alans, Sueves, and Vandals.  I have read that some of the barbarians came from far north, and thus it is **POSSIBLE** that **SOME** of them were born in Scandinavia.
6. And considering that there were contacts between Romans and Indians and Chinese, there could have been some unrecorded contacts of various types between Romans and Scandinavians.

So the answer is vikings no, Scandinavians yes.

Comment: Rome seceded from the Empire around 731 AD over iconoclasm controversy and conficsation of the pope's estates in Sicily by the emperor. At that time the empire was undivided. So what's the point of calling this question illogical? There is no much distance between 731 and 795.

Comment: @Anixx I presume you are aware that the Roman Empire *was* divided in the 5th century and that its two parts fared a bit differently since? And that the territories controlled by Constantinople in the West in the 8th century were very small (and, ifirc, confined only to some parts of Italy)?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - For most of us westerners, the last Roman emperor was Romulus Agustulus in 476 (if not earlier). But the Byzantines didn't call themselves "Byzantines". They said they were the Roman Empire right to the end. In Russia, which was in the Byzantine sphere at the time, it wouldn't shock me if they taught it Anixx's way rather than ours. That kind of different perspective is one of the things I value about having him here.

Answer (score 11):

I presume you're not talking about the Byzantine half of the Roman Empire here. [Those ties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varangians#Byzantine_Empire) are well known.

So, taking the subject line of your question, Romans of the western half of the Roman Empire meeting Vikings would be impossible because Rome fell before the label Viking was generally applied to Scandinavians.

Taking the text of your question, the answer regarding trade is yes, but mainly [through intermediaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic-Roman_contacts#Trade_aspect).

Regarding seriously scouting for invasion, I don't think so, but one cannot prove a negative.

Comment: This question might be deemed as inappropriate,but how Roman was the Byzantine Empire in the middle ages?eg Was their military structure run the same way?Did they still have gladiators?

Comment: @turinsbane They did not have gladiators but they did have chariot races. Their military was very different from the earlier romans as the strongest part of their army was the cavalry. However they did see themselves as romans and the name "Byzantine" is only given by later historians to denote the differences.

Comment: What does the fall of Rome have to do with the question? Why wouldn't there be trade relations or other contacts between Romans (western Romans, based in Rome, Italy) and Vikings in the 9th or 10th century?

Comment: @bof, by the time the Vikings started their raids the Franks were controlling the northern part of the Roman Empire. Listing their contacts with the Vikings doesn't seem to answer the question. Amd I'm not even going to start with the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Roman_Empire

Comment: @bof because you need to constrain the question in some fashion. After all, tourists today going from Rome, Italy to the Scandinavian peninsula _could_ be said to _be encountering vikings_....

Comment: @CGCampbell I understood the question to be about real Vikings in the Age of Vikings, not modern-day Scandinavians. I would have thought, with all those Vikings cruising the Mediterranean, and some of them being Christians, at least a few of them would have visited The Eternal City, where, whoever else they might find, they would surely meet some Romans.

Comment: @bof, you assumed that we're talking about Scandinavians *from the Age of Vikings*, then surely we must be talking about Romans *from the Roman Empire* and not Italians from Rome or Germans from the Holy Roman Empire (which was no Empire, not Roman, and not very Holy). For a question such as this, you have to define your terms. **Romans** generally means the Republic, the Empire, and the after the split the Western Empire.

Comment: This is a bit like  "I was the king of Babylon, and you were a Christian slave."!

Comment: What do u mean by "Rome fell"? Rome seceded from the Empire around 731 AD over iconoclasm controversy and conficsation of the pope's estates in Sicily by the emperor.

Comment: @Anixx, I interpreted "Rome" as "what is generally called the Roman Empire."

Comment: @o.m. so what? Rome seceded from Roman empire between 731 and 800. In 731 it was just a conflict with emperor over theological matters and formal breakup happened around 800. I think a turning point was 751 when the last Roman exarch was killed by Lombards in Ravenna.

Comment: @Anixx, when a question asks about "the Romans" I assume that it is about the Republic or Empire (before 410). People who talk about later periods tend to use names like "the Byzantine Empire", "the Ostrogoths" or "the HRE". I mentioned that assumption in my answer.

Comment: Oh my god. 410? What happened in 410? "the HRE" in any form appeared AFTER 800. It is the consequence of the iconoclasm controvercy and Lombard offensive I mentioned above.

Comment: In 410 the Visigoths entered Rome. Just one of many steps in the decline of Roman power, but a symbolic one. The western remains of Roman Empire were clearly on the defensive and further conquest to the north of Germania was out of the question. That was what the original poster had asked about, after all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32233/discussion-between-o-m-and-anixx).

Comment: @Anixx What ARE you on about with your constant repeats about 731? What did the synod of Rome have to do with any supposed secession of the city of Rome from ... what? The Byzantine Empire?

Answer (score 6):

Leaving aside the questions whether Scandinavians during the first centuries CE could be called "vikings", the answer is that they did encounter them. The Cimbrians were a people who invaded Italy and fought the Romans about 100 BCE. The Cimbrians are said to have come from the Cimbrian peninsula, identified with Jylland in Denmark.

As for Roman invasions of Scandinavia, there was really no way or point to it since they could and would not control continental Germania following the battle of Teutoburg forest.

Answer (score 1):

No they did not. The romans, I suspect, never came up that far north. They did, however deal with the similar goths.

Comment: So the Scandinavian raiders that invaded Rome were essentially the same people or culture as the Vikings,with the same religion,would that be accurate?

Comment: That might as well be accurate, possibly not with the same religion, however, and not unified.

Answer (score 1):

The Roman Empire, that is to say, the Western half of the Roman Empire, had fallen /collapsed around 476 AD/CE, approximately 325 years before the first Viking ships set sail from Scandinavia. When the Vikings emerged on the world historical stage, Rome, as well as much of the Italian peninsula, were slumbering through "The Dark Ages". So chronologically speaking, it would have been impossible for The Romans to have had any type of encounter with The Scandinavian Vikings.

Geographically speaking, as far as we know, the Romans never traveled towards Scandinavia; the most Northern city within The Roman Empire was Cologne in Northwest Germany/The Rhineland-(or if you prefer, York, in Northern England).  The last architectural Roman remnant in Northern Europe, is Hadrian's Wall, located in the North of England-(though you could also include the Antoinne Wall in Southern Scotland).

In short, the Romans, even during the final years of their Empire, would probably have not known of the existence of Scandinavia or its indigenous peoples and certainly would have not known of or encountered The Vikings.